# Buildx failed with error: "No such file or directory" when trying to push docker on Github

Tags: java, docker, maven, jar, dockerfile

I'm very new to Docker and I'm trying to get my Github repository setup with a docker when I push an update. However, when the github workfile script goes to push my code to Docker I get the following error.

```
Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1164878607/target: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1164878607/target: no such file or directory
```

It appears Docker can't access the file I set for it in my Dockerfile yet no amount of tweaking with the code appears to fix it, aside for me completely removing the COPY tag which renders my Docker unrunnable, though it does send. I'm using maven compiler plugin along with maven shade plugin and have setup my pom.xml file accordingly.

**Here is my Github WorkFile:**

```
name: Docker

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Set up JDK
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3.3.0
      with:
        java-version: 18
        distribution: adopt

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean package
      
    - name: Login to DockerHub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2.0.0
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}

    - name: Build and push Docker images
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3.0.0
      with:
        push: true
        tags: sudden/discordbot:latest
```

**Here is my DockerFile:**

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY target/discordbot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**What I've tried:**

- Copying another random file in my "src" directory.
- Changing the name of my jar file and changing the path.
- Changing my WORKDIR.
- Changed the Docker's "context" and other tags in my Workfile.

Any help is appreciated. This might be a simple fix, but I've been stuck on it for a day despite my best efforts so asking here is a last resort. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the filesystem state before the docker build is run. A common command for this is `tree`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you haven't excluded your `target` folders in your .dockerignore file.

That's what fixed it for me after several days of despairing search...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and at end it was because on my GitHub repository the folder `target` was not.
After push it the workflow worked.

I leave it here my docker-publish.yml if some want use to guide.

```bash
name: Generate Docker Image and Publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    tags: [ 'v*.*.*' ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          push: true
          tags: laurocorreia/reactive-api:latest
```